# How do I disable the default font list from being embedded with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, jspdf, custom-font

I've recently begun an evaluation of jsPDF for PDF generation with the final output being for printing purposes. For a current test I'm running I'm embedding a custom font into the PDF. However, I'm noticing in the generated PDF that the entire default font list also gets embedded into the PDF.

**Fontlist (Defaults + Custom Font):**

```
{
  "helvetica":[
    "normal",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "bolditalic"
  ],
  "Helvetica":[
    "",
    "Bold",
    "Oblique",
    "BoldOblique"
  ],
  "courier":[
    "normal",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "bolditalic"
  ],
  "Courier":[
    "",
    "Bold",
    "Oblique",
    "BoldOblique"
  ],
  "times":[
    "normal",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "bolditalic"
  ],
  "Times":[
    "Roman",
    "Bold",
    "Italic",
    "BoldItalic"
  ],
  "zapfdingbats":[
    "normal"
  ],
  "ZapfDingbats":[
    ""
  ],
  "symbol":[
    "normal"
  ],
  "Symbol":[
    ""
  ],
  "Arial":[
    "normal"
  ]
}
```

In the outputted PDF's properties I can see all of these embedded:
[image]

So my question is how do I disable the default fonts from being embedded? I'd like to just embed fonts that are actually needed by the contents of the document.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this feature doesn't exist in versions up to including 1.5.3 (latest at time of posting). However, the contributors have indicated that the following will work in a future version:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({ putOnlyUsedFonts: true });
```

Source: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2272